# jquery animate in sequence without callback function

Tags: jquery

I would like to animate different DIVs sequentially. Is there a way to force JQuery to process its queue in the middle of my code? Something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myHugeNumber; i++){

    var divName = '#Div' + i;
    $(divName).animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "slow");

    $.ProcessQueue() // Once finished animating, continue with FOR loop.
}
```

I am fully aware that you can pass a callback to the `.animate` function and this can be achieved with some recursive voodoo, however this would require a lot of retooling in my code. And I'm a stubborn, stubborn man.  Is there a quick and dirty method to force JQuery to process its queue on-the-fly?

Comment: If you do not want to use the callback you could use "setTimeout" where the time is "slow" (450 ms I belive) * i

Comment: @John '$(divName).delay(450*i).animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "slow");' seems to work as well. Interesting approach here.

Answer (score 0):

I know this uses the callback, but the code seems simpler than the for loop. I thought I would throw it out there.

```
var maxI = myHugeNumber;
var curI = 0;
startAnimation();

function startAnimation(){
   var id = '#Div' + curI;
   $(id).animate({'left': '-=50px'}, 'slow', function(){
      curI++;
      if(curI<maxI){
         startAnimation();
      }
   });
}
```